# SHA MD5 TO 512 Migration Isuue SQL Database

Tags: sql, hash

We have migrated our password hashing from MD5 to 512 Hashing on the SQL Server End.
The problem is that each user has a unique hash stored in the database even if the passwords are same(,due to the encryption technique that I cannot disclose).
For The QA guys we have the same password for testing ...after migration to sha512 how can we keep one password hash for all the QA testers??

Answer (score 0):

By design, if you are salting your passwords, this is impossible in normal circumstances as each salt will be unique (assuming your system works as designed). If you manually update the password hash and use a consistent salt (you are using a random salt and storing it with the password, right?), you can all have a common hash.

Why would you want a common hash?

Comment: common hash so that all QA testers have the same password

Comment: @abbas: You should have different hashes for the same password. See: salt.